# Is is possible to skip the login page when the only option is a 3rd party?

Tags: identityserver3

I have a scenario where a group of users will only have the ability to authenticate with a 3rd party login. Is it possible to pass an additional parameter that would skip the login page and automatically redirect the user to the 3rd party login page and avoid having to press the button for the 3rd party?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to influence the login workflow.

The client application can include a hint to identityserver which external provider to use - this is done via the `acr_values` parameter (idp:name_of_ext_idp).

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

You can also statically configure the ext provider per client (set `EnableLocalLogin` to false, and `IdentityProviderRestrictions` to the name of the ext. provider).

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html

Furthermore you can also handle the `PreAuthenticateAsync` method on the user service and dynamically set the `Idp` property on the `SignInMessage`

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

Comment: Hey it works for me in local but when deployed to dev it does not work, I passed idp:aad. you know why?