# ASP .NET Core identity server default login page as Microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have integrated the identity server together with Azure AD login for the current web app. May i know how do i immediately redirect user to Azure AD Microsoft login page when they are not authenticated, instead of showing the identity server login page?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218573/1752270) is about IdentityServer3 but still should be valid for [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Is this what you looked for?

Comment: Will have a try on it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [leastprivilege](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672453/leastprivilege) & [AndrewSilver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752270/andrewsilver) Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members .

> " There are a couple of ways to influence the login workflow.
>
> The client application can include a hint to
> [identityserver](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html)
> which external provider to use - this is done via the  `acr_values`
> parameter (idp:name_of_ext_idp).
>
> You can also statically
> [configure](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html)
> the ext provider per client (set  `EnableLocalLogin`  to false, and
> `IdentityProviderRestrictions`  to the name of the ext. provider).
>
> Furthermore you can also handle the  `PreAuthenticateAsync`  method on
> the [user
> service](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html)
> and dynamically set the  `Idp`  property on the  `SignInMessage` "

For example :

if you have named  **Azure AD**  as identity source provider – `aad` then you just need to pass this type of values as `acr_values`

**`idp: aad`**

For more information please refer this Blog : [Skip Identity server login page for Azure AD in identity server 4](https://neelbhatt.com/2020/03/07/skip-identity-server-login-page-for-azure-adauto-login/)